# nodejs express - case sensitive URL's

Tags: node.js, express, case-sensitive

How to make URL's case sensitive?

## app.get()

```
app.get('/([a-z]{2}/)api*', function(request, response){});
```

Here this app.get() catch both `/EN/api` `/eN/api`

What can I do so it only catches lower case URL's like `/en/api` ??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From express.js [api docs](https://expressjs.com/api.html)

> **case sensitive routing** - Enable case sensitivity, disabled by default, treating "/Foo" and "/foo" as the same

You can change the defaults like so:

```
app.set('case sensitive routing', true);
```

Comment: Is there a way to force the path to lowercase? The rationale being that it would prevent duplicate urls and help SEO stay organized.

Comment: I could never get this to work in Express 4.  I also tried app.enable('case sensitive routing') but it still took any URL case.  I finally solved mine by using regular expressions instead of strings.  That worked perfectly.

Comment: Use this:

router = express.Router({
  caseSensitive: true
});

Comment: Remember, you can always search the source code: https://github.com/expressjs/express/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=case+sensitive&type=Code

Comment: I believe this package handles just the thing @Costa - https://github.com/iZettle/express-lowercase-paths

Answer (score 5):

```
app.set('case sensitive routing', true);
```

**works only if u don't use in other files**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
```

if in our case same as above, just do this (in each file):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({caseSensitive: true});
```